# filtering a List before binding to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created a class which has three attributes. I created a `List` collection of that object.

I've used that collection for filling a `DataGridView`. I want to filter the data from the `DataGridView`.

How can I filter the list collection?

Comment: What version of .Net?  Can you use LINQ?  Where does the data come from?

Comment: i'm using .net 2005 & my data is from the sql server database & i'm adding these records by converting it to the object of my class & then i'm adding these objects in my list collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic function for it like..

List= List.FindAll(delegate(class obj)
            {
                return obj.name=="abc";
            });

Here "obj" is a object of your class and the "name" is a property by which we can filter property.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a list collection and you are using .Net 2.0, You don't have the LINQ support. In that case one option would be do the filtering before getting the objects in the list.

i.e. You get the Data from SQL Server into a DataTable and then have multiple Dataviews (1 for each filter). From these views you can populate your list objects.